# Drive not detected in Windows 7 but Ubuntu detects it

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I recently bought a Seagate Expansion 3TB (STBV3000300) external hard drive and tried running it on my computer with Windows 7 installed on it. It is not being detected by the computer. I tried reconnecting it to the different usb ports in the same computer but still no success. I tried using Disk Management Utility of Windows, the Hardware and Device Troubleshooter, but nothing seems to work.

In order to ensure that there is no fault with the motherboard or any of the usb ports, I used another Seagate Hard Drive in the same usb port and it worked fine. Then I installed Linux Ubuntu 12.04 on the same computer and the same 3TB works fine in Ubuntu.

For more details of the steps I tried refer here : http://forums.seagate.com/t5/FreeAgent-Products/Seagate-Expansion-3TB-STBV3000300-Driver-not-detected-in-Windows/td-p/183410

PS : I know there was an already existing thread at [Windows 7 not detecting external hard drive but Ubuntu is detecting. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/484607/windows-7-not-detecting-external-hard-drive-but-ubuntu-is-detecting-why) but I don't think that is the same issue as mine (hence I don't think this is a duplicate)

Comment: Same question arises here what do you see when you use `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: I am not sure how am I supposed to run |sudo fdisk -l| (in Windows) since that is where the drive is not detected. It's detected perfectly fine in Ubuntu.